# How to check if a Task returned null in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm attempting to interact with .NET tasks from F#, and as a result awaiting for Tasks sometimes results in a null being returned instead of the underlying type (eg: the Task itself timing out from a networking call). The issue is that I do not know how to check for this in F# if the underlying return type of the Task doesn't allow null checking. Here is a trivial example demonstrating my predicament:

```
task {
    let! a = Task.Run(fun () -> Some 1)
    if isNull a then 0 //null checking not allowed, type system insists must be Some, None
}
```

How do I check for *a* being null explicitly? If I remove the ! (remove the awaiting) and do just a `let a = Task.Run(fun () -> Some 1)`, then a Task is immediatley returned, which of course isn't null. It's rather only the result which can become null, but if I await the result, or do a .Result, then F# insists it's an option type, which does not allow null checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box the value first:

```
if isNull (box a) then ...
```

Boxing makes it an `obj`, and you can do a null check with it.